# Create a list of Button in Cocos2dx

Tags: cocos2d-x

When I create a list of button and I addTouchEventListener for it, like below code

```
for (int i = 0; i < btmPlay.size(); i++  )
{
    btmPlay.at(i)->addTouchEventListener([&](Ref *sender, ui::Widget::TouchEventType type){
        if (type == ui::Widget::TouchEventType::ENDED)
        {
            CCLOG("%i", i);
        }
    });
}
```

when I touch to the first button, the result is 12 ( btmPlay.size() = 13).

What errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your closure, you're capturing the variable `i` by reference, and that's why clicking any button will print the same value, in this case 12. If, instead, you capture the variable `i` by value (by replacing `[&]` with `[=]`) then each button will print a different value in the range 0-12.

Btw, capturing `i` by reference in your example is also wrong, because by the time the closure is invoked, the variable is already out of scope, and printing it is UB.

Comment: If the answer solves your problem, please consider accepting it by clicking on the hollow checkmark to the left of it. You will gain some reputation and it's also an incentive for users to answer other questions you may have.